# nginx upstream an ufw

Tags: nginx, ufw

I have a WSGI server on port 8080 and Nginx with following setup:

```
server {
     location / {
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
     }
}
```

when I enable UFW I can't access my page in browser

ufw status:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

error in nginx:

```
2015/01/25 08:13:45 [error] 26794#0: *2691 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "xxx.com
```

Why is the connection blocked?

EDIT:

```
iptables -L -vnx
```

pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   57516  4694967 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    8902  1230762 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 36792 packets, 9209532 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

```
ip6tables -L -vnx
```

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ufw6-before-logging-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-before-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-after-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-after-logging-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-reject-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-track-input  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ufw6-before-logging-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-before-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-after-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-after-logging-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-reject-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       0        0 ufw6-track-forward  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       8      536 ufw6-before-logging-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       8      536 ufw6-before-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       7      472 ufw6-after-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       7      472 ufw6-after-logging-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       7      472 ufw6-reject-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0
       7      472 ufw6-track-output  all      *      *       ::/0                 ::/0

Chain ufw6-after-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-after-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-before-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-reject-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-track-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-track-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw6-track-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

```
netstat -panet
```

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          374867      12241/python
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          349464      8600/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          9366        936/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      106        12369       1909/postgres
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.241:22       x.x.x.158:56800    ESTABLISHED 0          239804      17360/4
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.241:59810    x.x.x.241:5432     ESTABLISHED 0          375928      12451/sshd: root
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.241:5432     x.x.x.241:59810    ESTABLISHED 106        375929      12499/postgres: pos
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          127.0.0.1:46202         ESTABLISHED 106        374933      12252/postgres: pos
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.241:22       x.x.x.158:57396    ESTABLISHED 0          257360      21050/0
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.241:22       x.x.x.158:57302    ESTABLISHED 0          255897      20759/5
tcp        0    400 x.x.x.241:22       x.x.x.158:56594    ESTABLISHED 0          239377      17265/3
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.241:5432     x.x.x.241:59811    ESTABLISHED 106        375934      12500/postgres: pos
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46202         127.0.0.1:5432          ESTABLISHED 0          374932      12241/python
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.241:59811    x.x.x.241:5432     ESTABLISHED 0          375933      12451/sshd: root
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.241:22       x.x.x.158:62839    ESTABLISHED 0          375767      12451/sshd: root
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          9370        936/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      106        12370       1909/postgres

Comment: Add `iptables -L -vnx`, `ip6tables -L -vnx` and `netstat -panet` outputs please.

Comment: so where is the port 8080?

Comment: both WSGI and Nginx are on same host, WSGI is running on 8080